# C++ How can I make an Array double its size, without using a vector or a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have an assignment where I am supposed to make 3 classes. The first class manages the second, and the second manages the third. However, inside the second class should be an array that stores all the objects of the third. The array is supposed to double its size whenever needed (like a vector), but I am not allowed to use a vector or dynamic arrays (new). I can't figure out how to do this. Can someone help?

Comment: It is impossible. Size-changing array is dymamic array.

Comment: How about using [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: Another way is never allowing for doubling of size to be needed.

Comment: Tricky things could have been done if we'd seen your original code. Why not show a [mre]?

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to use a `linked list` here.

Comment: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) is useful as a linked list.

Comment: You can't, since you've over-constrained your problem. The size of an array is fixed in C++ when it is created. By stating that you can't use `vector` or "dynamic arrays" - which are options to emulate a resizeable array, depending on what operations are performed on them - then you've eliminated all available options. Other options, like a linked list, do not function like arrays (e.g. elements are not guaranteed to be contiguous) and typically use dynamic memory allocation (which, if you can't use it to emulate a resizable array, you probably can't use in a linked list either).

Comment: *I cant figure out how to do this* -- Maybe that is the answer your teacher is looking for -- it can't be done.

Comment: This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the actual assignment and what is your thought?

Comment: Yes this looks like an XY problem.  Maybe you have decided to use this impossible "dynamic array" for this problem, but in reality, the problem isn't solved using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an array cannot change in C++. It has the same size through its entire lifetime. As such, there is no way to "double" the size of an array.

Your description of the task is somewhat unclear. But it seems to me that your task is to implement a vector container (without using the existing `std::vector` of course). This can, and indeed *should* be done without using `new[]`.

The way vector container is implemented is that you allocate "raw" block of storage using an allocator. You can simply use `std::allocator` for this if you don't need to support user defined allocators. Within the storage, you can create dynamic objects using `std::uninitialized_XYZ` functions from the standard library.

To double the size of this internal "array", the algorithm is to allocate a new block of storage, then `std::uninitialized_move_n` the elements from the old to new storage, then `std::destroy_n` the objects that were moved from, then deallocate the old block of storage.